# Plotting a histogram using datetime data from strptime

Tags: r, datetime, plot, histogram, posixct

Here is what my data look like

```
Tue Feb 11 18:21:45 +0000 2014
Tue Feb 11 18:22:03 +0000 2014
Tue Feb 11 18:22:05 +0000 2014
```

Each row is an occurrence of an event. I'm trying to plot this data into a histogram.

Since the times are down to hours, minutes and seconds and I have a weeks worth of data. My histogram bins need to be based on days. So i can see actual significant change.

Here's my code so far..

```
Time_Data <- read.csv("Twitter_Data_2.csv")

Time_Data_Strptime <- strptime(data[,1], format ="%a%b%d %I:%M:%S %z%y")
```

followed by

```
hist(x=Time_Data_Strptime[,1], breaks="hours")
```

Im getting this error:

> Error in lapply(X = x, FUN = "[", ..., drop = drop) : 
>     argument is missing, with no default

I'm new to R studio, so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

edit: Sample from typing `dput(head(Time_Data))`

```
"Wed Feb 12 07:12:15 +0000 2014", "Wed Feb 12 07:12:55 +0000 2014", 
"Wed Feb 12 07:13:48 +0000 2014", "Wed Feb 12 07:15:53 +0000 2014", 
"Wed Feb 12 07:16:28 +0000 2014", "Wed Feb 12 07:20:11 +0000 2014", 
"Wed Feb 12 07:20:39 +0000 2014", "Wed Feb 12 07:20:47 +0000 2014",
```

edit2: Sample from typing `Time_Data_strptime`

```
   [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [42] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [83] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [124] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

edit3: Sample from Time_Data_strptime

```
[1] "2014-02-11 23:19:56" "2014-02-11 23:20:04"
[3] "2014-02-11 23:21:06" "2014-02-11 23:21:15"
[5] "2014-02-11 23:21:30" "2014-02-11 23:22:02"
```

Comment: please provide a sample of your data editing the output of `dput(head(Time_Data))` to your Q.

Comment: Typed the code and got this output (just a sample): "Wed Feb 12 23:52:42 +0000 2014", "Wed Feb 12 23:52:43 +0000 2014",

Comment: It should return a data structure, which can easily be loaded to reproduce your problem. for example `dput(c(1,2,3))` returns `c(1,2,3)` which then can be copied easily

Comment: I've edited on to my post the results from typing the code. even though its just a head there are many lines still...

Comment: can you show us a sample of Time_Data_Strptime? I tried to come figure out what happens. Turns out, all Time_Data_Strptime are `NA`

Comment: Striptime is just suppose to allow R to understand what each part of the string represents. Returning Time_Data_strptime is just a complete mess but i'll add it to my question anayways

Comment: Just tried `format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"` and it seems to work.

Comment: I just found out that it depends on how your system locale is set. That means for me working on a machine in German, I have to substitute Oct to Okt.

Comment: I tried using that format but when trying to plot the histogram I got the same error as before...

Comment: @loki is there a specific setting or form I need to be using R in for histograms to work? Im still learning the bascis of it. Right now im just using the console...

Comment: First I would start with getting the datetime format right. Making a histogram of `NA`s doesn't seem to make sense

Comment: @loki My Time_Data_strptime is now showing actual values instead of NA now... ill add a sample to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me:

```
Time_Data <- read.table(text = "Tue Feb 11 18:21:45 +0000 2014
Tue Feb 11 18:22:03 +0000 2014
Tue Feb 11 13:22:05 +0000 2014", head = F, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = F)
```

1. Using `POSIXct` instead of `strptime` since there is a `hist.POSIXct` method. (First change your system locale to the english one if necessary)

   ```
   Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
   Time_Data_Strptime <- as.POSIXct(Time_Data[,1], format ="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
   ```
2. Then use `hist` like this:

   ```
   hist(x=Time_Data_Strptime, breaks = "hours", freq = TRUE)
   ```

Further information about that can be found in [`??hist.POSIXt`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.POSIXt.html)

[image]

Comment: Time_Data_Strptime <- strptime(data[,1], format ="%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %z %y") I've currently got this to show actual values. Ive shown a sample in my question

Comment: @Liam: I edited my answer. now it contains all steps.

Comment: Works a treat, thanks so much. Turns out removing the [,1] from inside the histogram line made a massive difference.

Comment: Of course. See strptime (or as.POSXct) returns a vector. Thus it only has one dimension. That is, you don't need to / can't access any columns (which you would by using x[, 1]). Glad I could help

Comment: @Liam Just one remark: I would advise you to use `%H` and `%Y` because you might run into troubles with the other options.